# Amazon S3 Storage upload very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using s3 api to upload files to amazon s3 bucket. For small images (~20ko) it's working fine. I can upload tens of images, no problem. But for videos (not so big, ~10Mo) when I upload one it's taking forever. And if i try with more than one, let's say three, the request ends up being bloqued. I tried both in local on my machine and on a hosted server I have. Same problem. I precise that I enabled transfer acceleration but no effect.

Here is the code I use

```
AWS.config.update({
      region: "eu-west-3",
      useAccelerateEndpoint: true,
        credentials: { accessKeyId: environment.amazonAccesKey, secretAccessKey: environment.amazonSecret }
});
var upload = new S3.ManagedUpload({
            params: {
              Bucket: "app-helenos",
              Key: `${this.user.id}/${encodeURIComponent(this.library.title)}/${file.name}`,
              Body: file,
              ACL: "public-read",
              ContentType: file.type
            }
});
```

Can someone help me to understand why I have this behaviour ?

Comment: Your bucket is located in eu-west-3?

Comment: yes it is located in eu-west-3

Comment: This might be helpful? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-slow-downloads-uploads/

Comment: What about data encryption? Are you doing that also? There is a quota for encryption of data based on region.

Comment: I'm not doing data encryption